# There is no Find extension method for List in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, find, extension-methods

I am working on a silverlight application and i figured there is no Find extension method for a List

say,

```
List<Something> list = new List<Something>(something);
list.Remove(list.Find(e => e.id == 10));
```

there isn't Find extension method am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was not included to reduce the size of the runtime.

It is recommended you use LINQ extensions instead, such as `First` or `FirstOrDefault`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<Something> list = new List<Something>(something);
list.Remove(list.First(e => e.id == 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the framework apparently, in order to reduce download size..

You could create your own extension method as outlined at the bottom of this article:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/67428/363321.aspx